# element of list with select options with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following select item:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Kiwi</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

and an input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="entry" />
<button type="button" onclick="verify();">Verify !</button>
```

If I want to verify, with JavaScript, if the input entry is an element of `mySelect` how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function verify() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("entry").value,
        options = document.getElementById("mySelect").options;

    for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (options[i].text === inputVal)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/HPYL2/

Comment: what about if i have 2 entries in the same input ? for example (Kiwi,Banana), it should return true, so what should i modify to make it work ?